# How to get histogram data object from matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Lets say I have a matrix `x=[ 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 ]`.
To look at its histogram, I can do `h=hist(x)`.

Now, `h` with retrieve a matrix consisting only the number of occurrences and does not store the original value to which it occurred.

What I want is something like a function which takes a value from `x` and returns number of occurrences of it. Having said that, what one thing `histeq` does should we admire is, it automatically scales nearest values according!

How should solve this issue? How exactly people do it?

My reason of interest is in images:

Lets say I have an image. I want to find all number of occurrences of a chrominance value of image.

Answer (score 1):

```
%Let's say:
X = [1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1 5 10];
Num = input("Please enter the number");
temp = X == Num;

%let's assume Num in this case is 4
%temp = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]

ans = sum(temp);
```

ans = 3

This is a quick and an effective way to find the number of occurrences of a particular value.

Comment: That's simple on `int`. Consider you have all decimal values and given a number `12.335`, it might not be in `X` but it might fit nearest to some number `n: 12.00` which has frequency. how to fix it?

Comment: That would be the function round(). round(12.335) will be 12. You can then use the above code. Note: round(12.5) is 13 and not 12.

Comment: For non-integers I would use a range e.g. X>11.5 & X<=12.5. This can give you a bit more flexibility than rounding depending on what you are interested in.

Comment: A similar alternative to your example is numel(X(X==4)); which gives the answer in a single line.